# dlsym ends in infinite loop

Tags: java, c++, dlopen, dlsym

I am trying to build a Linux library(*.so) to use it in a Java application. This library itself loads an dll-file with native functions.

This is my C++ code:

```
__delspec(dllexport) void __cdecl GetDllVersion(void){
    typedef int(*GetDllVersion)(int*,int*,int*,int*);

    void* lib = dlopen("~/lib.dll",RTLD_NOW);
    cout << "Loading Symbol..." << endl;
    GetDllVersion getVer=  (GetDllVersion) dlsym(lib,"GetDllVersion");

    dlclose(lib);
```

}

The code was compiled with `wineg++ -shared lib.cpp -o libexports.so -Wl,--no-as-needed -ldl` without errors.

The Java application prints out "Loading Symbol..." in a loop and then terinates without any message. I could determine that this has to do something with dlsym().

With `nm -D lib.so` I could look inside the lib.so. The function GetDllVersion() is indeed a symbol inside this library.

Can somebody tell me why there is a infinite loop and wyh the Java VM is terminating?

Regards Wurmi

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
void* lib = dlopen("~/lib.dll",RTLD_NOW);
```

will always fail, because `dlopen` does not do tilde-expansion (in general, *only* shell does). You *really* should check `dlopen` return value.

This line:

```
GetDllVersion getVer=  (GetDllVersion) dlsym(lib,"GetDllVersion");
```

is equivalent to `dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, ...)` (because `RTLD_DEFAULT == 0` and `lib == NULL`) and as such returns you a pointer to the function you are already in, resulting in infinite recursion, and eventual crash due to stack exhaustion.